# Pass on variable: best practice using modules

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, module

I'm making a school assignment and am asking myself which of the following code is most logic.

The focus of my question is on the way I use my variables. Is it better to give the value to the function as a parameter or to call the variable like I did the first example.

This one:

```
var TEST = function()
{
    my.testVariable = "testing";

    SECONDFCTION.testfunction();

    return my;
}(TEST || {}, jQuery));


var SECONDFCTION = function()
{
    my.testfunction = function()
    {
        // SOME CODE 

        console.log(SECONDFUNCTION.testVariable);
    }

    return my;
}(SECONDFCTION || {}, jQuery));
```

Or this one:

```
var TEST = function()
{
    var testVariable = "test"

    SECONDFCTION.testfunction(testVariable);

    return my;
}(TEST || {}, jQuery));


var SECONDFCTION = function()
{
    my.testfunction = function(testVariable)
    {
        // SOME CODE 

        console.log(testVariable);
    }

    return my;
}(SECONDFCTION || {}, jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing arguments is almost always the better and more natural pattern.

Relying on global variables is errorprone and gets completely messy when you do multiple function calls. Also, if you have two relatively independent modules like in your example, you don't want to [couple them too tightly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)).